# geodjango check PointField in PolygonField

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango

I have two django models:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    geometry = models.PolygonField() 

class Position(models.Model):
    coordinates = models.PointField()
```

I am trying to check if a Position is  geographically contained inside a Region:

```
def check(region, position):
    return position.coordinates.intersect(region.geometry)
```

But it always return **False**, even when the Position is contained inside the Region (I am rendering both the PointField and the RegionField with django-leaflet).
I also tried using:

```
def check(region, position):
    return position.coordinates.within(region.geometry)
```

but no results so far. Here is the test data that I am using (geojson):

```
{"coordinates": [46.2071762, 11.1245718], "type": "Point"}
{"coordinates": [[[11.102371215820312, 46.21939582902924], [11.106491088867188, 46.22111800038881], [11.134214401245117, 46.22188999070486], [11.140050888061523, 46.21791115519151], [11.141080856323242, 46.21422899084459], [11.137990951538086, 46.207695510993354], [11.13412857055664, 46.20122065978115], [11.12485885620117, 46.198844376182535], [11.102371215820312, 46.21939582902924]]], "type": "Polygon"}
```

Any hint on what the problem could be? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is logical, I guess.Point's latitude and longitude should be swapped.
I mean

```
{"coordinates": [11.1245718, 46.2071762], "type": "Point"}
```

Instead of

```
{"coordinates": [46.2071762, 11.1245718], "type": "Point"}
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you!